# 2 iPhone to act like as central and peripheral beacon when in background

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am working on an application using core bluetooth within iOS. I am sending and receiving data across 2 devices no problem. The data transfer (a single string) occurs even when 1 of the devices is in the background as I have setup bluetooth to be active in the background.

However, if I have both devices in the background then the string is not sent or received by either phone. Is this a fundamental limitation on core bluetooth?

All I am looking for is the other device to store a unique identifier of the other device when both the apps are closed.

Basically can I have the devices communicating when the apps are both in the background? I know iBeacon has its limitation so that is why I am using core bluetooth.

If not, this seems crazy!

**EDIT**

To clarify, I have not posted code as I am looking for clarification as to whether it is even possible to pass data between 2 devices acting as a beacon using Core Bluetooth when they both have the app in a sleeping/closed state.

Currently it stops detection when both are closed, however if one app is open, then it works.

Comment: Curious why this got downvoted as I can't find documentation highlighting this

Comment: Show some code. How are you triggering the data transfer when a device is in the background.

Comment: @Paulw11 Maybe I wasn't clear. I DO NOT have an issue with how to pass data between 2 devices. What I think may not be possible and am I looking for clarification is, if its possible to do with BLUETOOTH when both devices have the app in a CLOSED/SLEEPING state.

Comment: What I am trying to ascertain is how do you initiate a data transfer when both devices are in the background?  One side or the other needs to issue a read request or a notify - if both apps are in the background then how do you trigger either of these events?

Comment: Surely using Core Bluetooth Background Execution peripheral and central Modes should be able to handle this?

Comment: @Allreadyhome I am indeed already using that, but it stops working when both devices are sleeping. Paulw11 - I was hoping BLE background modes would be enough to do this? Its looking less possible to achieve currently.

Comment: BLE can run in the background, but only to respond to read/write requests or respond to notifications that a characteristic has changed.  If both apps are in background mode how can a read/write request be issued or a characteristic updated.  You need some other background mode to actually generate or request the data that you are trying to exchange